# Release a grunt project properly

Tags: javascript, maven, gruntjs, nexus, maven-release-plugin

I'm using Nexus to store my static Web artifacts.

As an ex-"Java Developer" I used to use [Maven release plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) frequently to deploy my built artifacts to Nexus. I'd like to find an equivalent for my Web project build using Grunt.

For now, I'm using [grunt-maven-tasks](https://github.com/smh/grunt-maven-tasks) to deploy artifacts to Nexus. The problem is that I can't find an equivalent maven:release as it's done in Java using Grunt.

The existing grunt-maven-task *release* command is just trimming the "-SNAPSHOT" part before deploying to Nexus. No SCM interaction is done (checking un-commited resources, tagging into SCM, changing version, commiting, etc.).

I'd like to find a real "release to Nexus" for Grunt projects. What solution do I have ?

Comment: You could log an issue with the developer to see if they can add the functionality, or, if you're up to it, fork the repo and code that functionality up yourself as a pull request.

Comment: I was indeed thinking about that... I'm asking here just in case someone has an existing solution or a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this article http://labs.bsb.com/2014/02/better-maven-releases-with-jenkins/, I finaly decided to implement an equivalent Release workflow **in Jenkins**.

I created a *Jenkins Freestyle Project* and used the *Release plugin* to add a configuration release build to my job.  Two release parameters `release_version` and `next_snapshot_version` are consided for the release. I also used some custom Groovy scripts using *Scriptler plugin*.

The release steps gets executed **after successful standard build**.

1. Execute a shell script with to install JS packages, use grunt-maven-task to deploy to nexus. The grunt-maven-task is bumping to the next snapshot version (minor here), so I reposition it explicitly to `$RELEASE_VERSION` to commit to SVN the current release version before tagging)

   `npm install
   grunt maven:release:$RELEASE_VERSION:minor
   npm version $RELEASE_VERSION
   svn ci -m "Bump release version $RELEASE_VERSION for release tag" package.json`
2. Run a custom Groovy script to tag my working copy to SVN. This script is using the `svn` command line tool (not detailed here).
3. Execute a shell script to bump package.json to the next SNAPSHOT version :

   `npm version $NEXT_SNAPSHOT_VERSION
   svn ci -m "Bump next snapshot version to $NEXT_SNAPSHOT_VERSION after release"    package.json`